# Can i start clisp without using xterm?

Tags: xmonad

In emacs, the clisp can run in its own buffer as below:

```
(defun clisp ()
    (interactive)
    (async-shell-command "clisp -q -modern -ansi" "*clisp*"))
(global-set-key "\C-c\C-l" 'clisp)
```

Without using emacs, we can use `xterm -e clisp` to run it. Can clisp be run inside a xmonad window without using xterm ?

Sincerely!

Answer (score 0):

Uh, doesn't the simple command `clisp` do what you want? If not, you'll need to clarify your goal.

Answer (score 0):

> Can clisp be run inside a xmonad window without using xterm ?

You could use a terminal emulator other than xterm, but other than that: no, you can not run a console application in its own window without using a terminal emulator.

Comment: why can emacs run clisp in its buffer ?

Comment: @z_axis Because emacs can run console applications in a buffer. This can be useful because you don't have to open another window outside of emacs to run it and you can use emacs's shortcuts to copy text between the buffers etc. Note that the functionality of `async-shell-command` is somewhat limited in that it doesn't support colored output and similar control sequences. So it's only a very limited "terminal emulator". But why would Xmonad go through the trouble of implementing its own terminal emulator functionality if the net effect (application runs in its own window) is exactly the same?